# Method is not called

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I created object with methods related with database and after this I lost connection with database because create method isn't even called. Can someone explain it?

**Before (It works):**

```
export const connection = createConnection();
```

Index file:

```
import { connection } from "./utils/database";

async () => {
  try {
    await connection;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

**After:**

```
export const connection = {
  async create() {
    console.log("not showing in console");
    await createConnection();
  },

  async close() {
    await getConnection().close();
  },
};
```

Index file:

```
import { connection } from "./utils/database";

async () => {
  try {
    await connection.create();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: This arrow function you are creating to wrap the try catch block is never called. It used to work before, because you were creating the connection in the other file when you call `createConnection();` the arrow function in index wasn't called either.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I changed this arrow function to self called anonymous function and it works now. (async () => { })()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This arrow function you are creating to wrap the try catch block is never called. It used to work before, because you were creating the connection in the other file when you call createConnection(); the arrow function in index wasn't called either.

```js
import { connection } from "./utils/database";

async () => {
  try {
    await connection.create();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}();
```

I understand the goal is that the entire execution of the program waits on the db connecting, but I think it would be better to only wait in functions that needs the db connection. Not sure how it would fit with the rest of your application.

```js
connection.create()
  .then(() => console.log('db connected'))
  .error(console.error);
```

Then there are some different options for how to wait for db connection.

1. The most simple is some check like `while(!dbconnection) {}`
2. Only attach the handlers that need the db connection once it is connected, using either an event, or in the `.then`.
3. Maybe some other way.